# Drop down list showing part of the text

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

My drop down list in IE9 are showing part of the text. For example, there is a selection called "Hello World". But when i select it, it shows "Hello".

I try disable the css and i found out that this css is causing the problem.

.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1.1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }

When i disable this font-family : Verdana or lower the size of the font, it shows. I can't change the core css file because it might effect some other parts. Any good suggestion that i can hack it up ? Thanks.

Comment: for the issue dont want to reduce the size of the font when it gives good look to the site. just set the width for the element where u display ex: `.ui-widget textarea{width:120px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have an explicit css width set on the drop down list. Create a new CSS file for your web application and add the following to it to allow the drop down to expand to fit the text within;

```
.ui-widget select {width: auto !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the particular control and specify the important tag to make sure it overrides all other css settings.

i.e.

```
.dropDownFont
{
    font-size: 11px !importnant;
}
```

or you can apply it to all select items using the select selector:

```
select
{
    font-size: 11px !importnant;
}
```